# Using broadcasted dataframe in pyspark UDF

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to use a broadcasted data frame in the UDF of a pyspark SQl application.

My Code calls the broadcasted Dataframe inside a pyspark dataframe like below.

```
fact_ent_df_data = 
       sparkSession.sparkContext.broadcast(fact_ent_df.collect()) 
def generate_lookup_code(col1,col2,col3): 
     fact_ent_df_count=fact_ent_df_data.
     select(fact_ent_df_br.TheDate.between(col1,col2),
                  fact_ent_df_br.Ent.isin('col3')).count() 
     return fact_ent_df_count 
sparkSession.udf.register("generate_lookup_code" , generate_lookup_code ) 
sparkSession.sql('select sample4,generate_lookup_code(sample1,sample2,sample 3) as count_hol from table_t')
```

I am getting local variable used before assignment error when i use the broadcasted df_bc. Any help is appreciated
 And the Error i am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vignesh/PycharmProjects/gettingstarted/aramex_transit/spark_driver.py", line 46, in <module>
    sparkSession.udf.register("generate_lookup_code" , generate_lookup_code )
  File "D:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\udf.py", line 323, in register
    self.sparkSession._jsparkSession.udf().registerPython(name, register_udf._judf)
  File "D:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\udf.py", line 148, in _judf
    self._judf_placeholder = self._create_judf()
  File "D:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\udf.py", line 157, in _create_judf
    wrapped_func = _wrap_function(sc, self.func, self.returnType)
  File "D:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\sql\udf.py", line 33, in _wrap_function
    pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
  File "D:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 2391, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
  File "D:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\serializers.py", line 575, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
  File "D:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 918, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "D:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\cloudpickle.py", line 249, in dump
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o24.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trying to contribute with a simpler example based on Soheil's answer.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

def check_age (_age):
    return _age > 18

dict_source = {"alice": 10, "bob": 21}

broadcast_dict = sc.broadcast(dict_source) # define broadcast variable

rdd = sc.parallelize(list(dict_source.keys()))
result = rdd.map(
    lambda _name: check_age(broadcast_dict.value.get(_name)) # Here you specify the broadcasted var `.value`
)

print(result.collect())
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about Spark Broadcast variable as a Python simple data type like `list`, So the problem is how to pass a variable to the `UDF` functions. Here is an example:
Suppose we have ages list `d` and a data frame with columns `name` and `age`. So we want to check if the age of each person is in ages list.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

l = [13, 21, 34] # ages list
d = [('Alice', 10), ('bob', 21)] # data frame rows

rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
b_rdd = sc.broadcast(rdd.collect()) # define broadcast variable
df = spark.createDataFrame(d , ["name", "age"])

def check_age (age, age_list):
    if age in l:
        return "true"
    return "false"
def udf_check_age(age_list):
    return udf(lambda x : check_age(x, age_list))

df.withColumn("is_age_in_list", udf_check_age(b_rdd.value)(col("age"))).show()
```

Output:

```
+-----+---+--------------+
| name|age|is_age_in_list|
+-----+---+--------------+
|Alice| 10|         false|
|  bob| 21|          true|
+-----+---+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to perform a multiple column filter on the broad casted data frame from inside the UDF. Each rows values needs to be used to filter and get the count and returned once the udf executes. In you r example can i know what is happening here udf_check_age(b_rdd.value)(col("age")). Is the col(age) passed as age list? I need to pass values from 3 columns then in that case it must be df.withColumn(count_age,udf_cheack_age(b_rdd.value)(col('age'),col(age2))).
Can you please suggest.?

Comment: So, you want to pass values from 3 columns with a broadcast variable to one function and get one output? like: `def func(col1, col2, col3, b_rdd)` ?

Comment: The Error is mostly because of the usage of dataframe object inside the UDF.
pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o24.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist

Comment: pls add the codes to the question, in the comment it's confusing!

Comment: My Problem is i don't have a list. I have a Dataframe. WHen i pass the datafra,me there is some pickling issue.