# PySpark- Error accessing broadcast variable in udf while running in standalone cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
@f.pandas_udf(returnType= DoubleType())
def square(r : pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    print('In pandas Udf square')
    offset_value = offset.value
    return (r * r ) + 10

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Spark").getOrCreate()

    sc = spark.sparkContext
    
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")
    
    offset = sc.broadcast(10)
    
    x = pd.Series(range(0,100))

    df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["x"]))
    df = df.withColumn('sq',square(df.x)).withColumn('sqsq', square(f.col('sq')))
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()   

   
    df.show()

    offset.unpersist()
    offset.destroy()

    spark.stop()
```

The above code works well if i run pyspark submit command in local mode
Submit.cmd --master local[*] test.py

Same code, if i try to run in standalone cluster mode, i.e
Submit.cmd --master spark://xx.xx.0.24:7077 test.py
I get error while accessing broadcast variable in udf

java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-bf6b4553-f30f-4e4a-a7f7-ef117329985c\executor-3922c28f-ed1e-4348-baa4-4ed08e042b76\spark-b59e518c-a20a-4a11-b96b-b7657b1c79ea\broadcast6537791588721535439' after copy to 'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-bf6b4553-f30f-4e4a-a7f7-ef117329985c\executor-3922c28f-ed1e-4348-baa4-4ed08e042b76\blockmgr-ee27f0f0-ee8b-41ea-86d6-8f923845391e\37\broadcast_0_python'
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:2835)
at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.moveFileToBlock(DiskStore.scala:133)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$TempFileBasedBlockStoreUpdater.saveToDiskStore(BlockManager.scala:424)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$BlockStoreUpdater.$anonfun$save$1(BlockManager.scala:343)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1298)

Without accessing broadcast variable in Udf, this code works fine.

Comment: It's because you can't access any variable from outside udf function. One possibility is create another parameter called offset_value and call square(f.col('sq'), f.lit(offset.value))

Comment: My understanding is broadcast variables are used to send only 1 copy of variables to executor nodes and they can be accessed in Udf using broadcast_var.value ,http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.Broadcast  i have requirement to broadcast dictionary values, f.lit(offset.value) doesnt help.

Comment: try import partial from function tools and create a partial function

def square(r : pd.Series, offset) -> pd.Series:

partial square(r, offset=offset)

Comment: It didnt help to solve my issue. I wanted to understand how to fix using broadcast variable in udf when i run in standalone cluster mode. The same code works fine if i run in local mode.

Comment: Here's an example of properly using UDF with broadcast variables. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041860/using-broadcasted-dataframe-in-pyspark-udf

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps to solve this issue. Thank you.